# Behavior difference between two cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The below query returns 8 teams which is correct.

**Query**

```
START league=node:League(name='September League') 
MATCH (teams)-[:CONTESTED_IN]->league
RETURN teams.name
```

**Result**

```
teams.name
Kakatiya Kings
Broncos
Dunwoody Blues
DOE Spikers
Atlanta Spikers
Wild Claws
Alpharetta One
Camden Rockers
```

However when I add **level** as another starting node, though not using it anywhere, it returns each team repeated twice. Any idea why the difference in the behavior

**Query**

```
START league=node:League(name='September League'), level=node:Level(name='Quarterfinal') 
MATCH (teams)-[:CONTESTED_IN]->league
RETURN teams.name
```

**Result**

```
teams.name
Kakatiya Kings
Broncos
Dunwoody Blues
DOE Spikers
Atlanta Spikers
Wild Claws
Alpharetta One
Camden Rockers
Kakatiya Kings
Broncos
Dunwoody Blues
DOE Spikers
Atlanta Spikers
Wild Claws
Alpharetta One
Camden Rockers
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no relation between `league` and `level`, what you are getting is the cross product of results, that is one `team.name` per node indexed in node:Level. So the result is correct if two nodes are found in the index.

If you change your query to

```
RETURN teams.name, level
```

you can check that.
To get unique results, add a `distinct`:

```
RETURN distinct(teams.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? Trying to generate the faulty result in http://console.neo4j.org/r/6lvxd8 does not give me any. If you can recreate it in the console, please file an issue!

Comment: I am running this query from neoclipse against 1.8.2 version of Neo4j